# Jquery navigation should get a selected class based on the active slide

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, reveal.js

I'm sure I close to the solution, the `<a>`Submenu Navigations should have a selected class while I use the slide arrow navigation.

Currently adds the class only on click. I'm not sure what to do. I put together the code below but does't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7R9D/14/

```
window.onhashchange = locationHashChanged;
    function locationHashChanged() {

        // MENU1
        if (location.hash === "#/slide1") {
             console.log('menu slide1')
            $('#menu2').addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('#menu2').removeClass('selected');
        }
        // MENU2
        if (location.hash === "#/slide2") {
            console.log('menu slide2')
            $('#menu2').addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('#menu2').removeClass('selected');
        }
        // MENU3
        if (location.hash === "#/slide3") {
            console.log('menu slide3')
            $('#menu3').addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $('#menu3').removeClass('selected');
        }

    };

    locationHashChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `navigate-right` and `navigate-right` DIV's to `<a>` tags with the appropriate hash value.

Comment: its a plugin (reveal.js) not sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix it myself. here below is the solution http://jsfiddle.net/L7R9D/18/

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
          <li data-index="0"><a href="#/slide1" class="see-all">go to first slide</a></li>
          <li data-index="1"><a href="#/slide2" class="see-all" >go to second slide</a></li >
          <li data-index="2"><a href="#/slide3" class="see-all">go to third slide</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
 var menu_items = document.body.querySelectorAll('#menu li');
    for (var i = 0, len = menu_items.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (menu_items[i].getAttribute('data-index') && !(menu_items[i].getAttribute('data-index').indexOf(event.indexh) == -1)) {
            menu_items[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);border-radius:5px');
        } else {
            menu_items[i].setAttribute('style', '');
        }
    }
```